# Python Command Arguments getting lost

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I've done some debugging and having some trouble tracing why the command line arguments aren't being picked up properly in the following code:

```
def ensure_dir(f):
   d = os.path.dirname(f)
   if not os.path.exists(d):
     os.makedirs(d)

def main(argv):
   files = ["assignments", "examples", "exams", "lecture_notes", "submissions"]

   selectterm = ""
   selectclass = ""
   try:
       opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "c:t:", ["class","term"])
   except getopt.GetoptError as e:
       print 'Question2.py -c <class> -t <term>'
       system.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
       print arg
       print opt
       if opt in ("c", "class"):
           selectclass = arg
       if opt in ("t", "term"):
           selectterm = arg


   print selectclass
   print selectterm
   filename = selectterm + "/" + selectclass + "/src/"

   for  x in files:
       directory = str(filename + x +"/")
       ensure_dir(directory)
       print directory
   symblink = "/usr/local/classes/eecs/" + selectterm + "/" + selectclass + "/src/README"
   os.symlink(symblink, "README")





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The problem seems to be in the for opt, arg in opts: loop, as the command line arguments never get put into selectclass and selectterm, but the syntax looks correct to me.  The values are present in the argv array, and do pop up in the loop when I print arg and opt.

Comment: The code is not intended properly, which means that your blocks may end in different places than you expect. Please post correctly indented code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to put an equal sign at the end of your long opts to indicate that you expect them to take a value--e.g., `["class=", "term="]`

Secondly, the opt returned includes the prefix dash(es). e.g.,

```
...
if opt in ("-c", "--class"):
    ...
```